How to avoid a notch in a rectangle drawn with `\cline` directives around a cell?
Consider the following two-column/one-row tabular environment. I've used \cline directives to draw a rectangle around the right-hand cell.

How does one avoid creating the little notch in the lower-left corner of the rectangle? (Aside: Loading the array package solves creating a similar notch in the lower-right corner.)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l|l|}
\cline{2-2}
Hello & World \\ 
\cline{2-2}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


Addendum: I've noticed that the notch issue doesn't arrise if the tabular environment consists of just one column; it appears to be important that there be at least two columns, with the rectangle starting in column 2 (or later).

you could \hhline command from the package of the same name

@DavidCarlisle - Many thanks for this suggestion. Indeed, replacing \cline{2-2} with \hhline{~|-} works! :-)

I wonder how many of your comments or answers I could find on this site saying to read booktabs doc and don't use vertical rules:-)

in relation to your first comment, it's like multicolumn the | is part of the column to the left (apart from the first column which has both)so a\clinelike a\multiclolumn` that adjusts the first column  rmoves the rule between the columns.

@DavidCarlisle - Indeed, I plead guilty to frequently answering tabular-related questions by recommending (a) not using vertical rules at all and (b) using the macros of the booktabs package in lieu of \hline and \cline. :-) I posted this \cline-related query in response to a follow-up comment, which had me stumped, to an answer I provided to a query from last year.

You could use \hhline command from the package of the same name.
\hhline{~|-}


Thanks! Just out of idle curiosity: Is the "notch behavior" of \cline{2-2} more a feature than a bug?

@Mico yes I think so (incidentally it would be different if you did not load array) but \cline doesn't really know the inter-column | is there so can't compensate for it (it would be even harder to know what to do if you had a column spec of l@{foobar}l and \cline had to account for the width of foobar
